# Read POM values in external application properties

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have the following properties in the pom file

```xml
<name>DemoApplication</name>
<description>Demo spring project</description>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

And I have a class that reads the properties from `application.yml`
But instead of using the `application.yml` under `src/main/resources` I am specifying the properties through an external file as follows

```sh
java -jar DemoApplication-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=application.yml
```

In this external application properties, I have the following attributes

```yaml
swagger:
    apiTitle: '@project.name@'
    apiDescription: '@project.description@'
    apiVersion: '@project.version@'
```

The issue is that the `@project.name@` and other properties are not being replaced as expected, but are read as-is.

How should the problem be approached?

Comment: how are you reading properties ? Post code

Comment: With the `@Value()`. It works when using the file under src/main/resources but doesn't work when the properties are in external files

Comment: Try using @PropertySources

Comment: As far as I'm aware, even `@PropertySources` bundles the properties file during the build phase. I am targetting the execution phase.

Answer (score 2):

According [that section of the official documentation of Spring Boot v2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html), you can configure it with :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <delimiters>
            <delimiter>@</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
        <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With `useDefaultDelimiters` set to `false` or to `true` depending on your configuration.

The others sections of that official documentation will be helpful for your use case, especially these one : "77.5 Use YAML for External Properties".

If nothing is working, why don't you are loading a custom Properties file ? It could be loaded as you need without any problem. Just reference it with the correct path when you are starting your program, and inside your program, test if your file `config.properties` is available and contains what you need to work with.

Of course, the Maven way of loading resources files is the best easy way to go, and it should be a simple Properties file too. I have done exactly that way inside the software I am released to manage my configuration :

1. Writing a `app.properties`
2. Loading that file with Maven at runtime with resource configuration
3. Expanding properties with classical syntax ${my.prop}
4. Run the program with a Maven task.

Of course, when you distribute your app as a jar, it is a bit different.
Maybe you can try to write your properties files within a Maven goal.